# Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have spent probably an hour attempting to get this figured out... I keep getting this error no matter what I try:

```
Cannot read property 'value' of null
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div id="login_box"><form class="form-inline" action="JavaScript: login();" method="post">
  <input type="text" class="input-small" id="login_username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <input type="password" class="input-small" id="login_password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="login_autologin" name="autologin"> Remember me  </label>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" name="login">Sign in</button>
</form></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/overall_js.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the related JS file (overall_js.js):

```
function login() {
$("#login_box").html("logging you in....");
console.log(document.getElementById("login_username").value);
$.post("user.php?mode=login", {
    username : document.getElementById("login_username").value, 
    password : document.getElementById("login_password").value,
    autologin : document.getElementById("login_autologin").value,
}).done(function(data) {
    result = JSON.parse(data);
    if (result.status == 3) {
        $("#login_box").html(
                "Welcome back, " + result.user_row.username + "!");
    } else {
        $("#login_box")
                .html("You was not logged in: , " + result.error_msg);
    }
});
}
```

Thanks if you can figure this out! I am also new to jQuery and JS so if anyone has any suggestions to make it more "Standard", any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Notice that you've misspelled `passowrd`, and that an object literal may not contain the same property name twice.

Comment: On which line did you got that error?

Comment: Use a javascript debugger (from your browser's development tools), to find out exactly where the error happens. Based on the error message, it seems like one of the three elements are missing, but given your HTML, they're all there. So you'll definitely need the debugger to help you here.

Comment: @Bergi thanks, that would have caused me a problem in the future. I updated that part. I am getting the error on this line: console.log(document.getElementById("login_username").value);

Comment: @torazaburo: Of course you can (and it's even valid HTML)? What docs do you refer to?

Comment: @827: Actually he should have a look at the [`submit` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line

```
$("#login_box").html("logging you in....");
```

replaces the content of your `<div>`. You remove the form and all input elements...

Comment: Duh... Thank you so much. I knew it was a stupid error on me. I just couldn't find it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

See corrections needed below, lines 6 and 7:

```
function login() {
    $("#login_box").append("logging you in....");
    var u = $('#login_username').val();
    var p = $('#login_password').val();
    var al = $('#login_autologin').is(':checked');
    console.log(u, p, al);
    $.post("user.php?mode=login", {
        username : u, 
        password : p,
        autologin : al,
    }).done(function(data) {
        result = JSON.parse(data);
        if (result.status == 3) {
            $("#login_box").html(
                    "Welcome back, " + result.user_row.username + "!");
        } else {
            $("#login_box")
                    .html("You was not logged in: , " + result.error_msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a problem in the future, but not a fix for this problem. I am getting the error on the line "console.log(document.getElementById("login_username").value);"

Comment: Cleaned it up a bit more. See if this helps

Comment: thanks, I used a little bit of this to clean up my code now that I got it working.